# how to declare a variable for document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to declare a variable for some elements using 'document.getElementsByClassName' and I know that this returns a list of nodes but I don't know how to call that out in code. I need all the elements with the particular class name to be called in that var. I have added some div tags with class attributes for example.

If I had ids, this is how my code would be:

```js
var texttop = 150;
var textleft = 150;
var h1 = document.getElementById('h1'); //Similarly, I want to declare var using class name method for classes

function movedown(amount) {
  texttop += amount;
  h1.style.top = texttop + 'px'; //does this 'h1' also change to something like "forEach((element) => element.style.top"?
}
```

```html
<input type='button' class="down arrow" onclick='movedown(20)' value=">">
<div id='h1' style='position:absolute;'> some text </div>
<div class="demo"> Hello </div>
<div class="demo"> Bye </div>
```

Comment: You need to loop over the returned list.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner, so I would really appreciate if you show me how to. That's the part I'm struggling over.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("someclass").forEach(element => { do stuff with element } )`